# What are the shortcuts available in the official GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, user-guide

What are the shortcuts that I can use in the [official GUI](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl+S: go to panel "Send"

Ctrl+R: go to panel "Receive"

Ctrl+K: go to panel "Verify Payment"

Ctrl+H: go to panel "History" (of transactions)

Ctrl+B: go to the panel "Address**B**ook"

Ctrl+M: go to the panel "Mining" (not implemented yet)

Ctrl+I: go to the panel "S**i**gn/Verify"

Ctrl+E: go to the panel "S**e**ttings"

Ctrl+Tab or Alt+Tab: cycle among panels in the order Dashboard, Transfer, History, AddressBook, Mining, Settings.

Ctrl+Shift+Tab or Alt+Shift+Tab: cycle among panels in reverse order.

I you press control, you will see the possibilities displayed.

[Source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/blob/47063790793874b63df51a7bcbc50bbb819fd80f/main.qml#L72)